# Why is putting in spaces in User Input not working?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to just make a choice based text game for fun. I have a problem with text input. I really need help as I haven't seen anyone else ask this before (It might be just I wasn't looking hard enough). Here is the problem

```
@echo off
echo You hear something
echo ..Wake up or Sleep?
set /p WoS= 
if %WoS% == "Wake up" goto Wake up
if %WoS% == Sleep goto Sleep

:"Wake up"
echo There was no one there.
pause
echo There are 2 doors, Left or Right?
set /p Door=
if %Door% == Left goto Left
if %Door% == Right goto Right

:Left
pause

:Right 
pause

:Sleep
exit
```

Definitely not the tidiest, but I'm trying.

I saw something about quotations but it didn't work. I want the user to be able to input `Wake up` rather than just one word. I think it treats the `wake` and `up` as different strings. How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot have a label like this: `:"Wake up"`, change it to `:Wake` and change `goto Wake up` to `GoTo Wake`. When using `set /p` you should use the following syntax, `Set /P "var=input prompt"`, to protect spaces in the input. and change your `if` comparisons to this syntax: `If /I "%var%"=="string(s)" …`.

Comment: `IF` comparisons are string literal.  If quotes are on one side of the comparison they have to be on the other side for the statement to be true.

Comment: spaces in user input **is** working. It's your `if` that causes trouble - bad syntax. Quote both sides of the comparison.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for the help! It works now

Comment: As you have defined selections for your required input, you should really use the `Choice` command for this task, instead of `Set /P`. I have provided some code as an example of it in use, you can also read up on its usage, by entering `Choice /?` at the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extension of my comment to aid you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Choice /C ws /N /M "You hear something, [W]ake up or [S]leep?"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Sleep

:Wake
Echo There was no one there.
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
Choice /C lr /N /M "There are 2 doors, [L]eft or [R]ight?"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Right

:Left
Pause
Rem You need a GoTo, or Exit statement here, to prevent running :Right below

:Right 
Pause

:Sleep
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help.